# Anyway to use the Ubuntu Bash shell in VSCode for Integrated or External Shell on Win10?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, windows-10, visual-studio-code

If I open a command shell (e.g. Win-X,c) I can type "bash" and open a Bash Shell. But when I try to configure VSCore to use bash.exe (in /Windows/System32) as the shell command it says it can't find it. I suspect it's the Electron security context, but I wonder if I'm missing a way. Here's what I've tried in my settings.json:

```
{
   ...

  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have Developer Mode turned on in Updates & Security, For developers. Then go to Programs and Features in Control Panel, Turn Windows features on or off, and tick Windows Subsystem for Linux (bets). Restart. First time you hit yor bash configured terminal from VSCode, it will prompt you to install Linux for Ubuntu on Windows. Then login when prompted or create new username/password.

Comment: And the correct value in VSCode settings for terminal.integrated.shell.windows is C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe